# Xcode5 compiling 64-bit app error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, cocoapods

I had an app works fine on Xcode5.0.2 with architecture armv7 & armv7s.But when I switch to "standard architecture" which plus arm64,it turns out all the third-party library managed by cocoapods went wrong,as shown below:

[image]

[image]

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this kind of issue already,what is the solution to this,hopefully you could give me some instructions,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue here is that the CocoaPods you use have not been modified yet to support the ARM64 architecture thus they cannot be linked when you build them. Likely you cannot use those pods until they are updated to support ARM.

You can fix the linker error by going to `project -> target of your project -> build settings` and **change architectures to default architectures** (e.g. ARMv7, ARM7s), and valid architectures to ARMv7, ARMv7s.
Also try setting 'build active architectures only' to YES in release and then execute `pod install` again.

Comment: By your means,must wait until the cocoapods team update a new version which support arm64,and then can I run my apps with arm64,right?

Comment: If all dependencies support it, yes. But that might take quite some time, so better not wait for it.